# WEB3.PHP Contract getEvents

Tags: php, ethereum, web3php

I am using this PHP library https://github.com/web3p/web3.php to make the requests to smart contracts on Ethereum from a PHP server.

PHP return no error but nothing is showed.

Ths smart contract has transfers in the Gnosis blockchain (low fees to test ;) ).
https://gnosisscan.io/tx/0xf628c8132d6f44610b67b81c6bd354c04c5ce7b4918e05b1bb566725966e40f0

Any idea why it doesn't work?

```
<?php

require  'web3php/vendor/autoload.php';
 
use Web3\Web3;
use Web3\Contract;
use Web3\Utils;

$contractAddress = '0xf628c8132d6f44610b67b81c6bd354c04c5ce7b4918e05b1bb566725966e40f0';

$fromBlock = '0x' . dechex(0); 
$toBlock = 'latest'; 


$contract->at($contractAddress)->getEvents('Transfer', 
[ 
  'fromBlock' => $fromBlock, 
  'toBlock' => $toBlock
], 

function ($err, $events) {
 
  if ($err !== null) {
      echo 'Error: ' . $err->getMessage();
      return;
  }
  foreach ($events as $event) {
      // Decodifica los datos del evento
      $from = '0x' . substr($event['data'], 26, 40);
      $to = '0x' . substr($event['data'], 90, 40);
      $value = Utils::toBn('0x' . substr($event['data'], 130));

      echo "From: $from\n";
      echo "To: $to\n";
      echo "Value: " . $value->toString() . "\n";
  }

});
```